# Trataré de encontrar alguien que me ayude/ayudará

Tags: gramática

¿Cuál opción es correcta?

> ¿De qué manera encontraremos camareros que **puedan/pueden** hablar Italiano, Alemán, Francés, Español y Ruso?

> Tenía un gato que **hable/habla** Ruso.

> Trataré de encontrar alguien que me **ayude/ayudará**.

Answer (score 2):

Nota inicial: Los idiomas y las nacionalidades se escriben con minúscula en español.

El subjuntivo es el modo de lo incierto. En la segunda oración, que está en pasado, no puede haber incertidumbre, porque el hecho ya ocurrió:

- Tenía un gato que **hablaba** ruso. (Era un hecho que lo hablaba, vaya gato)

En los otros dos casos, puede usarse subjuntivo o indicativo, pero el subjuntivo es más usual:

- ¿De qué manera encontraremos camareros que **puedan**/(pueden) hablar italiano, alemán, francés, español y ruso?: Si se usa "pueden", estoy dando por sentado que existen camareros tan políglotas; en cambio, "puedan" sugiere que no es seguro que tales camereros efectivamente existan.
- Trataré de encontrar **a** alguien que me **ayude**/(ayudará): Nuevamente, el subjuntivo es mucho más habitual, porque no es seguro que encuentre a esa persona.

(Se usa "a" porque "alguien" es objeto directo de persona. En cambio: Trataré de encontrar algo que me ayude.)